# Catch token word in bash 'heredoc'

Tags: regex, pcre, heredoc

The beginning of a 'heredoc' string in bash usually looks like

```
cat <<EOF or cat << EOF
```

i.e. there may or may not be a space between the two less-than characters and the token word "EOF". I would like to catch the token word, so I try the following

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.45 2021-06-15

  re> "^\s*cat.*[^<]<{2}[^<](.*)"
data> cat << EOF
 0: cat << EOF
 1: EOF
data> cat <<EOF
 0: cat <<EOF
 1: OF
```

As you can see in the string where there is no space between the << and EOF, I only catch "OF" and not "EOF". The expression must match exactly two less-than signs and fail if there are three or more. But why does it gobble up the 'E' so that only "OF" is returned?

Comment: This part `[^<]` means any char except `<` but it does consume a single char, which is the `E` in `<<EOF` You could match optional spaces instead or `\h*` in pcre

Comment: OK, how do I match exactly two consecutive and not one or three '<' characters, then?

Comment: For the example strings like this `^\h*cat\h+<<\h*(.*)` https://regex101.com/r/Z8ZU2z/1

Comment: If I put three <<< in the string, your expression doesn't fail. It must fail.

Comment: I see, then like this `^\h*cat\h+<<(?!<)(.*)`

Comment: That seems to be it, thank you! Your comment should be converted to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern using are using a negated character class `[^<]` which matches a single character other than `<` which in this case is the `E` char in the string `<<EOF`

For your examples and using pcre, you could match the leading spaces and then match `<<` without a following `<`

```
^\h*cat\h+<<(?!<)(.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `cat\h+` Match `cat` and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `<<(?!<)` Match `<<` and assert not `<` directly to the right
- `(.*)` Capture optional chars in group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8jB6Lr/1)

Comment: [It appears](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-here-document-in-bash-programming/) that Bash's HEREDOC terminator must be at least one character long and cannot begin with a whitespace, and that zero or more whitespaces (or possibly spaces) can appear between `>>` and the terminator (e.g., `...>> EOF`). If so, I think you would want `^\h*cat\h+<<\s*([^<\s].*)`.

Comment: ....or just match (i.e., no capture group) `^\h*cat\h+<<\s*\K[^<\s].*`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah yes, if it should be at least 1 character long you can match a non whitespace char other than `<` Another option `^\h*cat\h+<<\h*+(?!<)(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/yWgnRY/1 Or to prevent some backtracking `^\h*cat\h+<<\h*+([^\s<].*)` https://regex101.com/r/7yMjcd/1

Comment: Er, "(e.g., `...<< EOF`)". Thanks for the reminder about `*+`.